# C++ Constructor

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is this weird colon-member syntax in the constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor)

If I define a class as shown below in C++:

```
class myclass
{
public: 
 myclass (unsigned int param) : param_ (param)
 {
 }

unsigned int param () const
{
 return param_;
}

private:
  unsigned int param_;
};
```

What does the constructor definition:
`myclass (unsigned int param) : param_ (param)` means and the benefit to the code?

Answer (score 13):

```
myclass (unsigned int param) : param_ (param)
```

This construct is called a **Member Initializer List** in C++.

It **initializes** your member `param_` to a value `param`.

---

***What is the difference between Initializing And Assignment inside constructor? &

What is the advantage?***

There is a difference between Initializing a member using initializer list and assigning it an value inside the constructor body.

When you initialize fields via initializer list the constructors will be called once.

If you use the assignment then the fields will be first initialized with default constructors and then reassigned (via assignment operator) with actual values.

As you see there is an additional overhead of creation & assignment in the latter, which might be considerable for user defined classes.

For an integer data type(for which you use it) or POD class members there is no practical overhead.

---

***When do you  `HAVE TO` use member Initializer list?***
You will have(rather forced) to use a Member Initializer list if:

Your class has a reference member
Your class has a const member   or
Your class doesn't have a default constructor

---

A code Example that depict the `HAVE TO` cases:

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        int &i;       //reference member, has to be Initialized in Member Initializer List
        int j;
        const int k;  //const member, has to be Initialized in Member Initializer List

    MyClass(int a, int b, int c):i(a),j(b),k(c)
    {

    }
};

class MyClass2:public MyClass
{
    public:
        int p;
        int q;
        MyClass2(int x,int y,int z,int l,int m):MyClass(x,y,z),p(l),q(m)
        {
        }

};

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    int z = 30;
    MyClass obj(x,y,z);

    int l = 40;
    int m = 50;
    MyClass2 obj2(x,y,z,l,m);

    return 0;
}
```

`MyClass2` doesn't have a default constructor so it has to be initialized through member initializer list.

Comment: Please stop spreading the term "initializer list" for this feature. Initializer lists are different.

Comment: Pray tell, what are "initializer lists"? To my knowledge, this is the correct term for this, and Google agrees...

Comment: @Tomalak: What is the correct term? "Initializer list" and "initialization list" are the only two I've ever heard or seen used. Important to get right, though, if you know different.

Comment: @Eli: This `{1,2,3,4,5}` is an initializer list.

Comment: @Benjamin: thanks. But I join Cody with the follow-up question.

Comment: The term in the grammar is `ctor-initializer`, which I employ. I'm not aware of any established colloquial phrase; however, your apparent invention, Als, of "member initializer list" seems appropriate to me.

Comment: `Member Initializer List` is the correct term to refer it, It is also commonly referenced as `Initializer List`, whether it is absolutely correct or not I do not know.

Comment: *"Your class doesn't have a default constructor"* -- Perhaps you should change that to say *"Your class has a member which doesn't have a default constructor"*

Comment: `ctor-initializer` includes the colon; `mem-initializer-list` is the actual list, so Als's use is hardly an invention.  However, regardless of what the grammar has to say on the subject, I've never seen anybody get confused by overloading the generic term "initializer list" to refer to both constructs, so I see no reason to get so fussy.  C++11 might change that, though.

Comment: @Dennis: There's simply no reason to use conflicting, ambiguous terminology when there's a _chance_ it will confuse somebody. Consider a language newcomer, for example. Why pick a silly term, when you can pick one that's both unambiguous and evidently written in the standard? It's win-win! :)

Answer (score 4):

The benefit to your code is that ... well, what?! That *is* your code. The benefit is that it does what it says. Compared to what alternative? To your code being different? Different how?

```
myclass (unsigned int param) : param_ (param) {}
```

The colon and following list is the `ctor-initializer` (do 
**not** call it "initializer list", which is something completely different in C++). It allows you to *initialize* members of the object.

Note that the following is not the same; you are only *assigning* to members after-the-fact:

```
myclass (unsigned int param) {
   param_ = param;
}
```

It won't really make a difference in this case, with an `unsigned int`, but once you start dealing with reference members and `const` members, and members with no default constructor, you find that you *must* initialise.