# How can I assign an instance variable without calling its constructor in C++?

Tags: c++, constructor

Basically, I have a class called VisaMux and a class called MuxPath.  MuxPath has a VisaMux private instance variable.  I want MuxPath's constructor to assign the instance variable a given VisaMux object without invoking an empty VisaMux() constructor.

```
5  MuxPath::MuxPath(const uint& Clk_sel, const uint& Lane_sel, const VisaMux& Mux){
6      clk_sel = Clk_sel;
7      lane_sel = Lane_sel;
8      mux = Mux;
9  }
```

This code results in the error:

```
MuxPath.cpp:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘VisaMux::VisaMux()’
VisaMux.h:20: candidates are: VisaMux::VisaMux(const std::string&, const uint&, const uint&, const std::vector<VisaLane, std::allocator<VisaLane> >&, const std::vector<VisaResource, std::allocator<VisaResource> >&)
```

As you can see, it errors on the first line (line 5), so it seems that somehow const VisaMux& Mux is invoking VisaMux(), which doesn't exist.  This also happens if I just do VisaMux Mux.

I don't want it to call an empty constructor for VisaMux because I want VisaMux to be created only by passing its constructor all the necessary parameters.

How can I do this?

Comment: The answers are below and tell you to use the initialization list syntax. I just want to add that you should prefer the use of the initialization syntax, otherwise you often construct objects in your parameter list twice. Once by default and once inside the body of your constructor. Also you should put items in  your initialization list in the same order you have them declared (see S. Meyers Effective C++ item 13)

Comment: @Andrew Wiens: Have a look at this Answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724626/c-constructor/6724639#6724639) explains you the difference between memberwise initialization and assignment inside constructor body

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the constructor initialization list:

```
MuxPath::MuxPath(const uint& Clk_sel, const uint& Lane_sel, const VisaMux& Mux)
       : clk_sel(Clk_sel)
       , lane_sel(Lane_sel)
       , mux(Mux)
{}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use member-initialization-list in the constructor as:

```
MuxPath::MuxPath(const uint& Clk_sel, const uint& Lane_sel, const VisaMux& Mux) 
   :clk_sel (Clk_sel),lane_sel(Lane_sel),mux(Mux)
{ //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ it's called initialization-list

}
```

Actually, in your code, all the member variables use *assignment* rather than their respective *constructor*, which means `mux` tries to get constructed with *default* constructor, even before it enters into the constructor of `MuxPath`. And since`VisaMux` doesn't have default constructor, its giving compilation error.

So by using the initialization-list, in which the syntax `mux(Mux)` invokes the copy-constructor of `VisaMux`, you avoid the invocation of default constructor of `VisaMux` which doesn't exist. And since the `mux` is already copy-constructed, there is no need to use *assignment* in the constructor body.

Answer (score 0):

```
   MuxPath::MuxPath(const uint& Clk_sel, const uint& Lane_sel, const VisaMux& Mux)
       : mux(Mux)
   {
       clk_sel = Clk_sel;
       lane_sel = Lane_sel;
   }
```

It's called "initialization list".

Answer (score 0):

```
class MuxPath {
  MuxPath(const uint& Clk_sel, const uint& Lane_sel, const VisaMux& Mux)
    : clk_sel(Clk_sel), lane_sel(Lane_sel), mux(Mux) {};
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're kind of asking how you can get red walls in your house without first installing wall studs.  If your `MuxPath` class contains a `Mux` variable, at some point during its construction, it's going to need to instantiate a variable of type `Mux`.  This implies that an instance of type `Mux` will be created, and the only mechanism to do that is with a constructor call.

This can either be a default, or no-arg constructor, a copy constructor, or a constructor that takes in some other argument.  The other answers show how to do that in the member initialization list.  But there's no way to get around the fact that at some point, some contructor for `Mux` will need to be called.