# Destructor protection in abstract base class is not inherited in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, visibility, destructor, compiler-generated

I found a memory leak in my code that was caused by calling only the base class destructor for objects. This problem is understood: I already added the `virtual` to the destructor of the interface class `MyÌnterface`. What puzzles me is that the compiler obviously created a standard destructor for my helper class `MyHelper`that is eventually called. I tried this with two different compilers.

This was very surprising to me, since I observed that most default implementations are not created if members or base classes introduce restrictions. **Why is the protection of the destructor not inherited?**

```
#include <iostream>

class MyInterface
{
public:
    virtual void doSomethingUseful()=0;
    // a lot more functions declared omitted
    virtual void doSomethingElse()=0;
    virtual void doSomethingIndividual()=0;
protected:
    /// protected destructor to forbid calling it on interfaces
    ~MyInterface() {} // HERE the virtual is clearly missing
};

/// a common base that defaults most functions implementations
class MyHelper: public MyInterface
{
public:
    void doSomethingUseful() {}
    // a lot more default implementations omitted
    void doSomethingElse() {}
};

class SomeImplementation: public MyHelper
{
public:
    SomeImplementation()
    {
        std::cout << "SomeImplementation ctr" << std::endl;
    }
    ~SomeImplementation()
    {
        std::cout << "SomeImplementation dtr" << std::endl;
    }
    void doSomethingIndividual()
    {
        std::cout << "SomeImplementation did it." << std::endl;
    }
};

/// user of MyInterface cannot delete object mi passed as parameter
int deleteSafeUsage(MyInterface& mi)
{
    mi.doSomethingIndividual();
    // would cause a compiler error: delete &mi;
}

/// usage restricted to MyHelper level, only exception is object creation
int testIt()
{
    MyHelper* h = new SomeImplementation;
    deleteSafeUsage(*h);
    delete h; // <- HERE the memory leak happens!
}
```

Here the output of the above example code, which "shows" the missing `SomeImplementation ctr`:

```
SomeImplementation ctr
SomeImplementation did it.
```

Comment: How do you know `MyHelper`'s d-tor got called? And can you please clarify what you mean by this: *most default implementations are not created if members or base classes introduce restrictions*?

Comment: @jrok try to uncomment the second line in `deleteSafeUsage()`, this will not compile.

Comment: @jrok (2) For example: compilers don't create constructors, if members are references or const or base class constructors take parameters.

Comment: (1) It does not compile because the destructor of `MyInterface` is protected. That proves nothing about the destructor of `MyHelper`. (2) None of the restrictions you mention apply in your example. About destructors - they're always generated (if not user declared), possibly as deleted, though.

Comment: But if what's troubling you is that `MyInterface`s destructor is `protected` - that's ok, it's still accesible from derived classes.

Comment: @jrok (2) This may be the answer: *destructors are always generated* where can I read that? (1) At least `~SomeImplementation` isn't called at the end of `testIt()`. The destructor of 'MyHelper` is empty so it will certainly be optimized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Constructors and destructors are not inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184341/c-constructor-destructor-inheritance). So why would their visibility be inherited?

You may want to check standard to be sure, but [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor) says this, emphasis mine:

> If no user-defined destructor is provided for a class type (struct, class, or union), the compiler will always declare a destructor as an inline **public** member of its class.

So, if you want `~MyHelper` to be protected, you must declare it explicitly.

Note, that if `MyInterface` had a virtual destructor, the implicit destructor of `MyHelper` would also be virtual. So this aspect is inherited, sort of. Again, you'll want to consult standard if you want to be sure, but this is mentioned in [c++ faq lite](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/virtual-dtors.html)

For completeness, here's [Herb Sutters](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill18.htm) guidelines on how to use virtuality in general and with destructors.

Comment: This makes sense, but if I read the [following section](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor#Deleted_implicitly-declared_copy_destructor), it seems dangerous to me to remember this simple rule that public default destructors are always generated.

Comment: True. It would be smart to always declare and properly define your destructors for non-pod classes. You'd also avoid this visibility surprise.

Comment: Would you agree that letting `~MyInterface` non-virtual and adding a virtual destructor to `MyHelper` would also be an option? (I indeed use both inherited levels for my `SomeClasses`)

Comment: In my opinion, all abstract classes should have virtual, public, defined destructors. That way you can easily destroy derived objects through interface without leaking memory.

Comment: That means: no more *completely abstract* base classes (==interfaces) in C++?

Comment: I suppose. What would be the advantage of *completely abstract base class* as opposed to *completely abstract base class except for the destructor*?

Comment: Nothing. The problem arose from my wish to prohibit deleting interfaces by mistake. My first version of this interface did not even contain a destructor declaration. And so the compiler built one, which I didn't like. I'd find **interface declaration in C++** more clear, if there was only **one public section**. But it's C++, and so there will be some (good?) reason for the ability to call a destructor for an object of an abstract class.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48257/discussion-between-user2079303-and-wolf)