# passing internal variables to a struct constructor C++

Tags: c++, constructor, struct

I am writing a binary search tree using a struct as the node. I need to initialize the variables in the struct with a struct constructor.

I have the following code which works just fine:

```
struct TreeNode{
    char name[20];
    int bribe;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

    TreeNode()
    {
        bribe = '\0';
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        name[i]= '\0';
    }
 }
```

I am required to initialize with a constructor that takes the arguments-->
TreeNode(char* name, int bribe, TreeNode* left, TreeNode* right)
i tried the following that is similar to an example I saw but I am getting some errors:

```
struct TreeNode{

    char name[20];
    int bribe;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

    TreeNode(char* name, int bribe, TreeNode* left, TreeNode* right);   
};


TreeNode::TreeNode(char* name, int bribe, TreeNode* left, TreeNode* right){ //***check this
    bribe = '\0';
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i ++){
        name[i]= '\0';
    }
}
```

So my question is about passing arguments to a constructor for a struct that initializes the structs varaibles. I cant seem to figure out if this happens inside or outside the stuct, or what the correct syntax is. I am trying to accomplish what the first code segment does but do so by way of passing arguments to the constructor. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:
Here are the errors I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Please tell us what are the errors, and what code causes it. That would help us help you.

Comment: Along with the answer below about member initializer lists, ever hear of the "this" keyword?

Comment: I attached the errors above, I tried the same implementation with the "this" keyword and still got the same errors.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using a **[Member Initializer List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724639/452307)** in C++ to initialize your class members.

Comment: Heh, that debate on whether "initializer list" is correct term, so silly. But not when it happens... Anyway, +1 for the link.