# Call constructor of member object

Tags: c++

I try to implement the amySQL, AND I want to intialize this connector intro test function.

```
class Foo
{
public:
    void Test();

protected:
    amy::connector mgr;

private:
    asio::io_service m;
};

void Foo::Test()
{
    mgr(m);
}
```

However when i want to compile i get this error:

```
error: no match for call to '(amy::connector {aka amy::basic_connector<amy::mysql_service>}) (asio::io_service&)'
  mgr(m);
```

What i do wrong here?
 Repository to amy sql  https://github.com/liancheng/amy

Comment: You don't "initialize constructors"  - constructors initialize things.

Comment: If it's `boost::asio` you are using and you have a relatively new version of boost, use `io_context` instead of `io_service`. `io_service` is just a typedef for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724626/c-constructor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize the `mgr` member inside the `Foo` class constructor, not in the `Test()` class method:

```cpp
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    void Test();

private:
    asio::io_service m;

protected:
    amy::connector mgr;
};

Foo::Foo() : mgr(m) // <-- initialize here!
{
}

void Foo::Test()
{
    // use mgr here as needed...
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, it should

Comment: Declaring `m` before `mgr` is super subtle but is crucial here, since members are initialized in order of declaration. If `m` is declared after `mgr`, then the initializer `mgr(m)` will use an unitialized object and will almost certainly cause Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @alterigel Amazing answer, you saved me. I was wondering why i'm gettin core crash, that was impossible to find out.  It seems that this was the cause, order of declaration was different from order of initialization. xD

Answer (score 1):

You could initialize the members in your class constructor's initialization list

```
Foo::Foo() : mgr(m) {}
```

Comment: The class name is `Foo`, not `Test`.  `Test()` is a method of the `Foo` class