# One line in class, makes whole app broken. 0xC000005 error

Tags: c++

Im trying to make a very simple text game and I get really irritating error.

This line is causing me these problems -> `Fleet fleet{1};`

Initially I tried to write it like this -> `Fleet fleet(1);`

But I got this error: `'expected identifier before numeric constant'`. And after some googling I found the solution `()->{}` and compilator didn't display any error. After running the application I found out that it isnt working. After removing this line, everything runs how it should be.
Also I was trying writing it like that: `Fleet() : fleet(1) {}` and then I get this error: `expected unqualified-id before ')'`.

I'm using C::B if thats helpful at all.

```cpp
class Ship{
public:
    int max_HP;
    int HP;
    int DMG;
};

class Fleet{
public:
    int amount_of_ships;
    Ship * ship = new Ship[amount_of_ships];


    Fleet(int fleet_size)
    {
        amount_of_ships=fleet_size;
    }
};

class Player{
public:
    string name;
    Fleet fleet{1}; //this line 
};
```

I really dont know why it does not work. Even if I create new Fleet object in main and write the same exact line, everything works how it should be. Also I should have mentioned it earlier - I'm doing absolutely NOTHING with Player class, and with Player's fleet at the moment. Any ideas on how to fix this? :/

Comment: Looks to me like `Fleet` needs a constructor.

Comment: Please read [C++ Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724626/c-constructor).

Comment: Turn on warnings.  Your compiler should be able to tell you what you are doing wrong in this situation.

Comment: Tell us what you mean by "it isn't working" and "it does not work". Be _exact_.

Comment: At this line `Ship * ship = new Ship[amount_of_ships];` `amount_of_ships` is still uninitialised.

Comment: @RichardCritten Answer in the answer section not here please and thank you

Comment: @SuvenPandey Simply read your up-to-date C++ book!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to note. Initialization of member variables proceeds in declaration order. Therefore, and according to...

```
int amount_of_ships;
Ship * ship = new Ship[amount_of_ships];
```

... `ship` is initialized after `amount_of_ships`. But here's the gotcha, you don't initialize `amount_of_ships`. You *assign* to it after initialization has run its course. And since you don't initialize it, it has an indeterminate value, the use of which causes undefined behavior.

You can use a c'tor initialization list:

```
Fleet(int fleet_size) : amount_of_ships{fleet_size}
{
}
```

Initialization will proceed in declaration order, and now `amount_of_ships` is indeed initialized. This may look a bit obscure to some, however.

If you are compiling C++14 and newer, then you can go full aggregate:

```
class Fleet{
public:
    int amount_of_ships;
    Ship * ship = new Ship[amount_of_ships];
};
```

This will make `Fleet fleet{1};` be aggregate initialization. The `amount_of_ships` member is initialized directly, and `ship` is initialized from the default member initializer.

But your best bet would probably be not to use raw pointers at all. Don't allocate things yourself, and favor the modern C++ route. You can use `std::vector`:

```
class Fleet{
public:
    std::vector<Ship> ships;

    Fleet(int fleet_size) : ships(fleet_size)
    {
    }
};
```

This makes the initialization simple *and* implicitly correct, since the constructor for `vector` will do the correct thing. It also has another major benefit. Now your class has a correct d'tor, copy/move c'tors, and assignment operators. All of which you didn't have to write yourself.

Comment: As an addendum, if you choose not to use a `vector` or similar type, you'll want to add a destructor to delete `ships`, along with (at the very least) a copy constructor & assignment operator.  Probably also a move constructor & assignment operator, too.

Answer (score 1):

You're consistently trying to use inline initialisers; that is, providing the initialiser for a member inside the class definition instead of with the constructor.

For your `Fleet` (after your syntax fix) [this is fine](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization), but your `ship` initialiser relies on a useful value for `amount_of_ships`, which is not provided until the constructor body. This happens *after* inline initialisers are run.

Just initialise your members in the normal manner using [the *ctor-initialiser*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/560648), I would.

Answer (score 0):

you are attempting to use a aggregated initializer list for a class that has a constructor which wont work and will result in many defined and undefined compilation errors, also you are trying to set the `Fleet` inside your member data on your class which will not work since its not a `constexpr` type, you need to simply have `Fleet fleet` inside your member data for `class Player` and then construct the fleet inside the Player constructor

```
Player::Player()
{
    this->fleet = Fleet::Fleet(1);
}
```

also this code`Fleet(int fleet_size) : amount_of_ships{fleet_size}` is incorrect as you are once again using aggregated initializer list where it is not needed, simply use

```
Fleet::Fleet(int fleet_size)
: amount_of_ships(fleet_size) \\ notice we use parentheses instead of curly brackets  
{

}
```

only use aggregated intializer list with structs that dont define a constructor or other special use cases which you can look up on your own,

i hope this helped.....